# Unable to start Shiny server

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean, shiny-server

I've hosted shiny-server on DigitalOcean Ubuntu 14.04.5 droplet with nginx.

Shiny server was working fine, but stopped working after I rebooted the droplet to resize the config. The issue hasn't occurred earlier.

I tried to restart shiny-server using `sudo start shiny-server`, but I get the status `start: Job failed to start`.

When I visit the Shiny app hosted at `/srv/shiny-server/`, I get the following nginx error.

```
An error occurred.

Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.
Please try again later.

If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should check the error log for details.

Faithfully yours, nginx.
```

Shiny-server error log:

```
    fs.js:439
          return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                         ^
        Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/var/run/shiny-server/shiny-server.pid'
            at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:439:18)
            at Object.createPidFile (/opt/shiny-server/lib/core/fsutil.js:121:15)
            at Object. (/opt/shiny-server/lib/main.js:82:15)
            at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
            at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
            at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
            at startup (node.js:119:16)
            at node.js:945:3
```

There is no `shiny-server.pid` at `/var/run/shiny-server/`.

My `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf` settings:

```
    # Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
    run_as shiny;
    sanitize_errors off;

    # Define a server that listens on port 3838
    server {
      listen 3838;

      # Define a location at the base URL
      location / {

        run_as shiny;

        # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
        site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

        # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
        log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

        # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
        # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
        directory_index on;
      }
    }
```

I'm not sure what the problem is. Tried searching online forums too but with no luck! Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Resolved the issue by creating a folder `sudo mkdir /var/run/shiny-server` and then enabling write permissions for Shiny user `sudo chown shiny:shiny /var/run/shiny-server/`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder `sudo mkdir /var/run/shiny-server` and then enable write permissions for Shiny user `sudo chown shiny:shiny /var/run/shiny-server/`